# Richfaces 4.X: Warn User of navigating away from page

Tags: javascript, navigation, richfaces

In javascript I have seen a couple of solutions of how to warn a user that they might lose data if they navigate away from a page.

Has Richfaces made it easy as pie to do this?  I am currently on 4.3.2.  I don't see anything in their documentation that describes this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure
This jQuery plugin claims to do what I need it to do.  It is a bit buggy, but it is a good start.